# How to pass the content of list one element at a time to a method?

Tags: python, list, nmap

I have a libnmap scanner script which basically works by collecting all the EIP from AWS and scanning them one by one, the function which collects all EIP looks like :

```
def gather_public_ip():
    ACCESS_KEY = config.get('aws','access_key')
    SECRET_KEY = config.get('aws','secret_key')
    regions = regions = ['us-west-2','eu-central-1','ap-southeast-1']
    all_EIP = []
    for region in regions:
       client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
       addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
       for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
         if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
            print eip_dict['PublicIp']
            all_EIP.append(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
       print all_EIP
       return all_EIP
```

This function basically returns me a list which looks like

```
['22.22.124.141', '22.21.149.191', '22.11.132.122', '22.11.227.241', '22.34.28.112', '22.34.211.227', '22.27.21.233',  '22.24.199.122', '22.11.113.171', '22.21.11.8', '22.33.31.14', '22.37.19.213', '22.24.121.112', '22.32.121.132', '22.24.21.1', '22.34.72.198']
```

The main function from which i call the above method then passes it to my actual scanner function which looks like :

```
  s = Scanner(config)

        # Execute Scan and Generate latest report
        net_range =  gather_public_ip() # config.get('sources','networks')  ## Call DEF
        #print type(net_range)
        r = s.run(net_range)
        s.save()   # save to pickle
```

The scanner class looks like:

```
class Scanner(object):
    """Container for all scan activies"""

    def __init__(self,cp):
        self.config = cp # read in ConfigParser object to get settings
        self.report = None

    def gather_targets(self):
        """Gather list of targets based on configured sources"""
        pass

    def run(self, targets="" ,options="-Pn"):
        #start a new nmap scan on localhost with some specific options

        syslog.syslog("Scan started")
        parsed = None
        nmproc = NmapProcess(targets,options)
        rc = nmproc.run()
```

Can someone please help me with the part where i can pass the values from the list to the run method one by one so that nmap can process it , right now it just sits idly

Comment: @DmitryTokarev While you were at it, why didn't you correct also the title and the tags?

Comment: @gboffi missed it :(

Comment: If `NmapProcess` can deal with only one IP address at once, you can use a _list comprehension_, `r = [s.run(ip) for ip in net_range]`. Of course the object that you'll have to deal with will be a list of the objects returned by your method.

Comment: you don't want to use a `for` loop to iterate through the list?

Comment: @DmitryTokarev I've just approved your new edit, thank you

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Can you elaborate what you mean ?

Comment: @gboffi I tried with the code change, didn't worked out, still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you pass in the arguments looks good. However, you don't have any code that actually uses the result.

Try changing `Scanner.run` like this:

```
class Scanner(object):
    ...
    def run(self, targets="" ,options="-Pn"):
        #start a new nmap scan on localhost with some specific options

        syslog.syslog("Scan started")
        parsed = None
        nmproc = NmapProcess(targets,options)

        nmproc.run_background()
        while nmproc.is_running():
            print("Nmap Scan running: ETC: {0} DONE: {1}%".format(nmproc.etc,
                                                                  nmproc.progress))
            sleep(2)

        print("rc: {0} output: {1}".format(nmproc.rc, nmproc.summary))
```

This is taken straight from [the docs](http://libnmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/process.html#using-libnmap-process).

Comment: inside the run() methond of scanner class?

Comment: this seems nice, but i actually use the `rc`, so if i just place `rc = nmproc.run()` before this , then this should work